# Get number of files in path reading by RDD

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I am reading a path in RDD. I know there are ways in java to read number of files in a folder. But is there any way get number of files present in that file.

Comment: could you please post the code which you are trying so it helps to understand little more clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to compute the number of files in a directory using spark could be to use `binaryFiles`. This functions creates one record per file and maps each file name to a `DataStream`.

```scala
// This will just count the files, without reading them
sc.binaryFiles("path").count
```

If you want to read the content of the files, have a look at `wholeTextFiles`.